# Can you replace a dead husband?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you get a new husband if yours died?

Comment: Pc, console? witch one?

Comment: @Skye Does it matter?

Comment: yes, can you use the console?

Comment: I think he asks for valid gameplay solutions instead of cheating

Answer (score 2):

Not if you're playing on console. Then, unless you have a recent save, you're out of luck...
On PC, there are certain console commands to revive NPCs. [Here's a list of console commands for PC.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29)